# Firebase Cloud Functions: 'Authorization failed' – IAM permissions issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I want to delete the data of a collection (with all its sub-collections) in Firebase Cloud Firestore. To accomplish this I use a callable Firebase Cloud Function and [a sample snippet from Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/tree/master/firestore/solution-deletes).

It uses `firebase-tools` to delete data recursively from Cloud Firestore with this function:

```js
const path = data.path;
await firebase_tools.firestore
  .delete(path, {
    project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
    token: functions.config().fb.token
  });
  return { path: path };
```

I generated a Firebase token and added the token to my Cloud Functions runtime configuration. Then I enabled the Identity and Access Management (IAM) API on my project in the Google Cloud console. In the IAM page of the Google Cloud console, I granted the service account called "App Engine default service account" the "Service Account Token Creator" role as stated in the [`README.md`](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/tree/master/firestore/solution-deletes#in-your-browser) of the code snippet.

However, when calling my Cloud Function I get this error message:

```
Error deleting recursively: FirebaseError: Authorization failed. This account is missing the following required permissions on project ***:

  datastore.entities.delete
  datastore.entities.list
  firebase.projects.get
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/requirePermissions.js:41:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/requirePermissions.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  children: [],
  context: undefined,
  exit: 1,
  original: undefined,
  status: 500
}
```

I already tried to add these permissions to the service account "App Engine default service account". This didn't solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

---

##### Update with additional info regarding the IAM roles:

The service account has access to the IAM roles "Editor", "Service Account Token Creator" and a custom role named "Custom - Recursive Deletion Firestore" as displayed in this screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of IAM roles of the service account "App Engine default service account"]

I created the custom role ("Custom - Recursive Deletion Firestore") to add the permissions from the error message above. These are the settings of the role:

[image: Screenshot of the detail of a custom IAM role]

Comment: Did you set the 'token' in the functions config? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, did that and also checked with `firebase functions:config:get`. The token is set.

Comment: Can you verify what role/s did you add in your IAM?

Comment: What are you using as for the `project` field? Can you also display what is the result when you run the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` in a function?

Comment: @RJC When I check the runtime environment variables of the Cloud Function at Google Cloud Platform > Cloud Functions > [my function] > Variables, the definition of `GCLOUD_PROJECT` is visible. It is the id of the GCP/Firebase project.

Comment: I suggest that you reach the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) for this, and also take a moment and review the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide.